# Subtracting values of only matching indexes in Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been working on a program to manage a store inventory using Pandas. For what I am working on now is subtracting the quantity ordered from the original and printing the inventory after the transaction. I created two dataframes to hold the original and the user's cart.

Inventory

| Items | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1.30 | 90 |
| Banana | 0.57 | 100 |
| Orange | 1.33 | 50 |
| Book | 15.0 | 50 |
| Notepad | 1.0 | 100 |

Cart

| Items | Cost | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 13.0 | 10 |
| Orange | 6.65 | 5 |

I've tried using the command `inventory['Quantity'] = inventory['Quantity'] - cart['Quantity']` to get a final result but it comes up as

| Items | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1.30 | 80 |
| Banana | 0.57 | NaN |
| Orange | 1.33 | 45 |
| Book | 15.0 | NaN |
| Notepad | 1.0 | NaN |

Does anyone know how to stop the other rows from coming back as NaN?

Comment: `inventory["Quantity"].subtract(cart["Quantity"], fill_value=0)`

Comment: It keeps giving this error                            `inventory['Quantity'].subtract(cart['Quantity'], fill_value=0) 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Such an error means that the variable `inventory` or `cart` is a list and not `pandas.DataFrame`. Otherwise, the Michael Cao solution is correct.

Comment: There is a typo `Apple` `Apples` in Items column values.

Comment: Found the issue. I was already using the name "cart" for the list I made the dataframe out of. I updated the name and the code works perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelCao Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Series.subtract` with `fill_value = 0` so that non-matched indices are subtracted by zero.

```
inventory["Quantity"].subtract(cart["Quantity"], fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach, and you can solve your problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the inventory data frame
inventory_data = {'Items': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Book', 'Notepad'],
                  'Price': [1.30, 0.57, 1.33, 15.0, 1.0],
                  'Quantity': [90, 100, 50, 50, 100]}
inventory = pd.DataFrame(inventory_data)

# Create the cart data frame
cart_data = {'Items': ['Apples', 'Orange'],
             'Cost': [13.0, 6.65],
             'Quantity': [10, 5]}
cart = pd.DataFrame(cart_data)

# Convert item names to lowercase for matching
inventory['Items'] = inventory['Items'].str.lower()
cart['Items'] = cart['Items'].str.lower()

# Merge the inventory and cart data frames on the "Items" column
merged = pd.merge(inventory, cart, on='Items', how='left')

# Subtract cart quantities from inventory quantities
merged['Quantity'] = merged['Quantity_x'] - merged['Quantity_y']

# Fill NaN values with inventory quantities
merged['Quantity'] = merged['Quantity'].fillna(merged['Quantity_x'])

# Select the necessary columns and rename them
updated_inventory = merged[['Items', 'Price', 'Quantity']].rename(columns={'Quantity': 'Quantity'})

# Convert the item names back to their original case
updated_inventory['Items'] = updated_inventory['Items'].str.capitalize()

# Convert the quantity column to integers
updated_inventory['Quantity'] = updated_inventory['Quantity'].astype(int)

# Print the updated inventory
print(updated_inventory)
```